# Como escrever um programa que preenche um vetor de 10 posições com números inteiros aleatórios entre 0 e 20?

Tags: python, array, numpy, int

Como faço para criar um vetor `v` de 10 elementos aleatórios em que cada elemento é um **inteiro** entre 0 e 20?

Tentei utilizar a função `np.random.random((1,10))`, mas a saída foi um vetor só de números decimais

Segue o que eu fiz:

```
#ENTRADA:
import numpy as np
v = np.random.random((1,10))
print(v)

#SAÍDA
[[0.41153214 0.72635035 0.28634792 0.10726119 0.07231721 0.53886811
  0.09092156 0.75656757 0.59052976 0.95628254]]
```

Comment: Apesar da duplicada sugerida acima não ter exatamente o mesmo título, creio que não será difícil adaptar as respostas que tem lá para o seu caso específico

Answer (score 4):

Para responder esta questão podes utilizar o seguinte código:

```
import numpy as np

v = np.random.randint(0, 21, 10)
print(v)
```

Observe que o vetor **v** será montado com **10** valores que pertençam ao intervalo fechado **[0, 20]**

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar o np.random.randint para gerar o número aleatório, neste caso os números podem repetir.

Este retorna uma lista:

```
v = [np.random.randint(0, 21) for i in range(10)]

type(v)
list
```

Este retorna um numpy array:

```
x = np.random.randint(21, size = 10)

type(x)
numpy.ndarray
```